# Handling/capturing a button click event as a priority in WinForms

Tags: winforms

This is the mock-up of a child window that I have in a Windows Forms application.

This will be shown when a button is clicked on the parent window.

[image]

When the child form opens up, the focus is in Text box1.

The Leave event on the Text box1 fires when the user tabs out of it or clicks on any button.
This triggers a validation:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value of Id.");
}
else {
 ... other logic omitted for brevity
}
```

Now the user can also click on the Cancel button to exit the form without doing any action.

Here, on the first try, the Leave event fires because the focus is in Text box1 when the Form is loaded so when the user clicks on Cancel for the first time the form does not close, instead the message box with validation message is shown.
On the second click, since the focus is no longer on Text box1, the Leave event does not fire and the form closes.

I can put the focus on any other control to handle this but for the sake of user experience I had to put the focus on Textbox1 since it's value decides the further logic of what is shown in Textbox2(Textbox1 can be left empty in which case nothing is shown in Textbox2 but that is not related to this question).

Tried this to see if I can get the Cancel button inside the Leave event of Textbox1:

```
Button b = sender as Button
```

b is NULL when Cancel is clicked.

What can I do to make the Cancel click work, without triggering the Leave event initially?

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: Validate the inputs when you click the `Save` button instead of the `Leave` events.

Comment: In addition, use an `ErrorProvider` rather than a message box.

Comment: Don't use Leave, the Validating event was made for this.  Set the Cancel button's CausesValidation property to false.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to supress the error message when the cancel button recieves the focus, simply check for the `cancelButton.Focused` flag in the leave event, then block the message if the cancel button got the focus.

Nevertheless, it is usually considered good practice to avoid modal dialog boxes if they are not required. So depending on your particular situation, you may decide to replace the `MessageBox` with a `ToolTip` instead, which will not entirely block the UI thread.